# Icons and Widgets disapeared after upgrade Kubuntu to 21.04 from 20.10

Tags: ubuntu, icons, kde-plasma

All icons and widgets disapeared after upgrading from Kubuntu 20.10 to 21.04.
Im using Latte Dock.

https://i.postimg.cc/25360czt/Screenshot-20210614-104953.png

https://i.postimg.cc/bYTz2KFy/Screenshot-20210614-080734.png

I have deleted icon-cache files, not solved.
Any ideas?

---

*Operating System: Kubuntu 21.04

KDE Plasma Version: 5.21.4

KDE Frameworks Version: 5.80.0

Qt Version: 5.15.2

Kernel Version: 5.11.0-18-lowlatency

OS Type: 64-bit

Graphics Platform: X11

Processors: AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=171543

Problem is caused by rogue Qt packages

```
sudo apt remove libqt5quick5-gles
```

Thanks to [Mamarok](https://forum.kde.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=216)!